# Detecting or deleting Worksheet_Deactivate code programmatically in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that creates a new worksheet in the active workbook and populates that worksheet with various transactions from all of the other sheets in the workbook looking for duplicate entries.

It lists all the possible duplicate entries and creates hyperlinks beside those entries linked to where the transactions are posted. When a link is clicked it creates a button at the destination to return to the sheet with the list of possible duplicate entries.

It also adds a Worksheet_Deactivate code to each sheet that will delete the button (if it exists) created from clicking one of the links on the new worksheet when the worksheet is deactivated.

Sometimes I run the macro more than once on a particular workbook which then adds a second Worksheet_Deactivate code to each sheet which causes errors when it tries to execute.

I was wondering if it were possible to do one of two things. First, is it possible to have the macro check to see if the Worksheet_Deactivate code exists before it enters the code (skipping the code when the code already exists)? If not, is it possible to just delete the code (using an error handler where the code does not exist) just before it enters the code?

Comment: You may add a hidden worksheet for data... In that worksheet, use a cell to store a value (0 or 1, for example) denoting whether the code existed or not...Initially set it to 0, and set to 1 after the deactivating code has been added....

Comment: I would like to avoid the use of hidden sheets though that method would work if I were inclined to do so. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to what I was looking for. In the beginning of the macro, I added:

```
Dim VBP As Object
Set VBP = ActiveWorkbook.PVBProject
Dim ln As Long
```

As the macro progresses, it goes through each sheet to pull information, the current sheet being worked on is set as ws1. Where the Worksheet_Deactivate code would be input, I added:

```
success = 0
With VBP.VBComponents("" & ws1.CodeName & "").CodeModule
    For ln = 1 To .CountOfLines
        If InStr(1, .Lines(ln, 1), "Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            success = 1
        End If
    Next ln
End With
If success = 0 Then
    "Bunch of stuff to add the Worksheet_Deactivate code"
End If
```